# C++ repeated definitions of class types?

Tags: c++, class

Good afternoon!

Sorry if the question seems rather vague, but here's some (incomplete) code for some context. Specifically, this is about the "UserInfo inputInfo" definition part as seen in the functions UserInfo::setUserInfo() and UserInfo::displayProfile() in the implementation file.

project02.cpp (implementation file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "project02.h"

using namespace std;

void UserInfo::setUserInfo()
{
    UserInfo inputInfo;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    int bYear;
    string city;
    string occupation;

    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> fName;
    inputInfo.setFirstName(fName);

    cout << "Please enter your last name: ";
    cin >> lName;
    inputInfo.setLastName(lName);

    cout << "You are now registered as: " << inputInfo.getFirstName() << " " << inputInfo.getLastName();
}

void UserInfo::displayProfile()
{
    UserInfo inputInfo;
    cout << "Profile Information:" << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << inputInfo.getFirstName() << " " << inputInfo.getLastName();
}

void UserInfo::setFirstName(string fName)
{
    _firstName = fName;
}

string UserInfo::getFirstName()
{
    return _firstName;
}

void UserInfo::setLastName(string lName)
{
    _lastName = lName;
}

string UserInfo::getLastName()
{
    return _lastName;
}
```

project02.h (header file)

```
#ifndef PROJECT02_H
#define PROJECT02_H

using namespace std;

class UserInfo
{
    public:
        string getFirstName();
        void setFirstName(string first);
        string getLastName();
        void setLastName(string last);
        int getBirthYear();
        void setBirthYear(int year);
        string getCurrentCity();
        void setCurrentCity(string city);
        string getOccupation();
        void setOccupation(string occ);
        void setUserInfo();
        void displayProfile();
    private:
        string _firstName;
        string _lastName;
        int _birthYear;
        string _currentCity;
        string _occupation;

};

#endif // PROJECT02_H
```

project02main.cpp (main file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "project02.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UserInfo inputInfo;
    inputInfo.setUserInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the question is: is there an alternative to repeatedly defining the object "UserInfo inputInfo;" each time for a different function in the implementation file?

Comment: I don't understand. Where are you trying to "redefine" it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I edited the post to make it more clear. I meant to say "repeatedly defining", as you can see that I did once for both functions.

Comment: why dont you just pass userinfo as an argument ?

Comment: You are creating a local variable of your class and modifying it. It is then discarded at the end of the function. Your actual object, on which the function is called, is unchanged.

Comment: Voting to close because the code is meaningless (based on some misunderstanding), its purpose is unspecified, and the question about an alternative is consequently also meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create objects of the same data type within methods of that datatype at this point - simply call setFirstname() and getFirstname() to use methods that will modify the same object that you are currently using.

Comment: Ah that works, thanks you! I have no idea why my professor's example included that.

Comment: It was probably an oversight on his part - happens to the best of us :)

Good luck with your project!